# Eikonal Equation with Data Given on Ellipse

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am having great difficulty solving the Eikonal Equation:

$u_x^2+u_y^2=1$      for $(x,y) \in  int(\Omega)$, $ u = 0 $ $ \partial\Omega$
where $\Omega$ is the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$.

The attempts that I have made so far are direct applications of M.O.C. By doing this in cartesian coordinates and applying the strip condition you are left helpless.

I believe that the best hope here will be applying the geometric interpretation of this particular version of Eikonal's equation. That is, the solution $u(x,y)$ represents the minimal distance from a point inside the ellipse to its boundary. I have not been able to find a parameterization that captures the degenerate line from foci to foci in the ellipise, which represents the values $(x,y) \in \Omega$ for which the solution will not be unique.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A slightly off-topic remark: [Eikonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal) is an adjective, not a name. So it's "the eikonal equation", not "Eikonal's equation".

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you transform to elliptic coordinates?

Comment: @mattos While elliptic coordinates helped and you can actually find a closed form solution, it involves solving a quartic equation to remove the parameterization variable. I believe the solution will only be found in a nice manner through an optimal control approach. Intuitively, he solution should represent level curves inside the ellipse being contracted continuously to the degenerate line.